# Calculating similarities of text embeddings using CLIP

Tags: python, word-embedding, cosine-similarity

I am trying to use [CLIP](https://github.com/openai/CLIP) to calculate the similarities between strings. (I know that CLIP is usually used with text and images but it should work with only strings as well.)

I provide a list of simple text prompts and calculate the similarity between their embeddings. The similarities are off but I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import torch
import clip
from torch.nn import CosineSimilarity

cos = CosineSimilarity(dim=1, eps=1e-6)

def gen_features(model, text):
    tokens = clip.tokenize([text]).to(device)
    text_features = model.encode_text(tokens)

    return text_features

def dist(v1, v2):
    #return torch.dist(normalize(v1), normalize(v2)) # euclidean distance
    #return cos(normalize(v1), normalize(v2)).item() # cosine similarity

    similarity = (normalize(v1) @ normalize(v2).T)

    return similarity.item()



device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model_name = "ViT-B/32"
model, _ = clip.load(model_name, device=device)

sentences = ["A cat", "A dog", "A labrador", "A poodle", "A wolf", "A lion", "A house"]

with torch.no_grad():
    embeddings = [(sentence, gen_features(model, sentence)) for sentence in sentences]
    for label1, embedding1 in embeddings:
        for label2, embedding2 in embeddings:
            print(f"{label1} -> {label2}: {dist(embedding1, embedding2)}")


Output


    A cat -> A cat: 0.9999998211860657
    A cat -> A dog: 0.9361147880554199
    A cat -> A labrador: 0.8170720934867859
    A cat -> A poodle: 0.8438302278518677
    A cat -> A wolf: 0.9086413979530334
    A cat -> A lion: 0.8914517164230347
    A cat -> A house: 0.8724125027656555
    A dog -> A cat: 0.9361147880554199
    A dog -> A dog: 1.0000004768371582
    A dog -> A labrador: 0.8481228351593018
    A dog -> A poodle: 0.9010260105133057
    A dog -> A wolf: 0.9260395169258118
    A dog -> A lion: 0.886112630367279
    A dog -> A house: 0.8852840662002563
    A labrador -> A cat: 0.8170720934867859
    A labrador -> A dog: 0.8481228351593018
    A labrador -> A labrador: 1.000000238418579
    A labrador -> A poodle: 0.7722526788711548
    A labrador -> A wolf: 0.8111101984977722
    A labrador -> A lion: 0.783727765083313
    A labrador -> A house: 0.7569846510887146
    A poodle -> A cat: 0.8438302278518677
    A poodle -> A dog: 0.9010260105133057
    A poodle -> A labrador: 0.7722526788711548
    A poodle -> A poodle: 0.999999463558197
    A poodle -> A wolf: 0.8539597988128662
    A poodle -> A lion: 0.8460092544555664
    A poodle -> A house: 0.8119628429412842
    A wolf -> A cat: 0.9086413979530334
    A wolf -> A dog: 0.9260395169258118
    A wolf -> A labrador: 0.8111101984977722
    A wolf -> A poodle: 0.8539597988128662
    A wolf -> A wolf: 1.000000238418579
    A wolf -> A lion: 0.9043934941291809
    A wolf -> A house: 0.860664427280426
    A lion -> A cat: 0.8914517164230347
    A lion -> A dog: 0.886112630367279
    A lion -> A labrador: 0.783727765083313
    A lion -> A poodle: 0.8460092544555664
    A lion -> A wolf: 0.9043934941291809
    A lion -> A lion: 1.0000004768371582
    A lion -> A house: 0.8402873873710632
    A house -> A cat: 0.8724125027656555
    A house -> A dog: 0.8852840662002563
    A house -> A labrador: 0.7569846510887146
    A house -> A poodle: 0.8119628429412842
    A house -> A wolf: 0.860664427280426
    A house -> A lion: 0.8402873873710632
    A house -> A house: 0.9999997615814209


The results show that a dog is closer to a house than it is for a labrador 0.885 vs 0.848 which doesn't make sense. I've tried cosine similarity and euclidean distance to check whether the distance measure was wrong, but the results are similar. Where am I going wrong?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the text embeddings from the output of `CLIPTextModel` ([number of prompts, 77, 512]), flatten them ([number of prompts, 39424]) and the apply cosine similarity, you'll get improved results.

This code lets you test both solutions ([1,512] and [77,512]). I'm running it on Google Colab.

```
    !pip install -U torch transformers 
    
    import torch
    from torch.nn import CosineSimilarity
    from transformers import CLIPTokenizer, CLIPModel, CLIPTextModel
    cossim = CosineSimilarity(dim=0, eps=1e-6)
    
    def dist(v1, v2):
      return cossim(v1, v2)
    
    torch_device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    
    models = [
        'openai/clip-vit-base-patch16',
        'openai/clip-vit-base-patch32',
        'openai/clip-vit-large-patch14',
    ]
    
    model_id = models[1]
    
    tokenizer = CLIPTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
    text_encoder = CLIPTextModel.from_pretrained(model_id).to(torch_device)
    model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained(model_id).to(torch_device)
    
    prompts = [
      "A cat", "A dog", "A labrador", "A poodle", "A wolf", "A lion", "A house",
    ] 
    
    text_inputs = tokenizer(
        prompts, 
        padding="max_length", 
        return_tensors="pt",
        ).to(torch_device)
    text_features = model.get_text_features(**text_inputs)
    text_embeddings = torch.flatten(text_encoder(text_inputs.input_ids.to(torch_device))['last_hidden_state'],1,-1)
    
    print("\n\nusing text_features")
    for i1, label1 in enumerate(prompts):
      for i2, label2 in enumerate(prompts):
        if (i2>=i1):
          print(f"{label1} <-> {label2} = {dist(text_features[i1], text_features[i2]):.4f}")
    
    print("\n\nusing text_embeddings")
    for i1, label1 in enumerate(prompts):
      for i2, label2 in enumerate(prompts):
        if (i2>=i1):
          print(f"{label1} <-> {label2} = {dist(text_embeddings[i1], text_embeddings[i2]):.4f}")
```

You'll get the same values for the [1,512] embedding

```
A cat <-> A cat = 1.0000
A cat <-> A dog = 0.9361
A cat <-> A labrador = 0.8171
A cat <-> A poodle = 0.8438
A cat <-> A wolf = 0.9086
A cat <-> A lion = 0.8915
A cat <-> A house = 0.8724
A dog <-> A dog = 1.0000
**A dog <-> A labrador = 0.8481**
A dog <-> A poodle = 0.9010
A dog <-> A wolf = 0.9260
A dog <-> A lion = 0.8861
**A dog <-> A house = 0.8853**
A labrador <-> A labrador = 1.0000
A labrador <-> A poodle = 0.7723
A labrador <-> A wolf = 0.8111
A labrador <-> A lion = 0.7837
A labrador <-> A house = 0.7570
A poodle <-> A poodle = 1.0000
A poodle <-> A wolf = 0.8540
A poodle <-> A lion = 0.8460
A poodle <-> A house = 0.8120
A wolf <-> A wolf = 1.0000
A wolf <-> A lion = 0.9044
A wolf <-> A house = 0.8607
A lion <-> A lion = 1.0000
A lion <-> A house = 0.8403
A house <-> A house = 1.0000
```

But the results have improved with the [1,77,512] embedding, and now the dog is closer to the labrador than to the house. Still, you'll get funny results such as the cat being more similar to a house than to a poodle.

```
A cat <-> A cat = 1.0000
A cat <-> A dog = 0.8880
A cat <-> A labrador = 0.8057
A cat <-> A poodle = 0.7579
A cat <-> A wolf = 0.8558
A cat <-> A lion = 0.8358
A cat <-> A house = 0.8024
A dog <-> A dog = 1.0000
**A dog <-> A labrador = 0.8794**
A dog <-> A poodle = 0.8583
A dog <-> A wolf = 0.8888
A dog <-> A lion = 0.8265
**A dog <-> A house = 0.8294**
A labrador <-> A labrador = 1.0000
A labrador <-> A poodle = 0.8006
A labrador <-> A wolf = 0.8182
A labrador <-> A lion = 0.7958
A labrador <-> A house = 0.7608
A poodle <-> A poodle = 1.0000
A poodle <-> A wolf = 0.7928
A poodle <-> A lion = 0.7735
A poodle <-> A house = 0.7623
A wolf <-> A wolf = 1.0000
A wolf <-> A lion = 0.8496
A wolf <-> A house = 0.8063
A lion <-> A lion = 1.0000
A lion <-> A house = 0.7671
A house <-> A house = 1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I needed. Would you mind explaining what I was doing wrong? Did I misunderstand what `model.encode_text(tokens)` does?

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure we are using the model as intended. I ran into similar results when also trying to compute sentence similarity with CLIP. The model tries to match pairs of (text, image) but we are using it to match (text, text), so nothing guarantees us that the distance `(<dog as text>, <house as text>)` really makes sense whereas the distance `(<dog as text>, <house as image>)` should make sense.

Comment: anecdotally, my results seem to fit the intuition. Two prompts that are similar tend to produce similar images (see my write-up [here](https://medium.com/@soapsudtycoon/prompt-engineering-trending-on-artstation-and-other-myths-part-2-d61e25a90517), and especially [this image](https://miro.medium.com/max/640/1*2tin8pUDKeJE1zZdalkIrA.png)). A concern I have is whether the magnitude of the similarity score is meaningful. if dist(prompt1, prompt2) == 0.9, dist(prompt1, prompt3) == 0.5  can I say that prompt3 is much less similar to prompt 1 than prompt 2 or is it only less similar?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the unpooled outputs like this. The [1,77,512] is (roughly) "The 512 dimensional embedding for each token, sequentially" for the 77 token context window. Intuitively, you want a shorter sentence that indicates the same object ("A house") to match closely to a longer one ("A house as it is stereotypically represented").. but because you've unfolded the entire context window you will penalize different length phrases since shorter examples will have 'filler embeddings' to make it match 77 tokens in length, and cosine similarity weighs each dimension independently.

Comment: Additionally - CLIP is trained to place the image representation and text representation of the same thing as close to 0 in cosine distance as possible. An intuition for a "text to text" comparison could therefore be "How similar would the thing that these sentences describe look?". Unfortunately CLIP (any ml model - really) does have a lot of inexplicable nonlinearities that create weird edge-cases. Ultimately CLIP itself advertises ~80% accuracy on academic datasets, and a reasonable rule of thumb is you should expect the same level of accuracy in your own usages too (sans finetuning).